# Complex sql query - count + having + group by - how fix query

Tags: php, mysql, sql

i'm looking for help with one quite complex query in sql.

Query should sounds like:  (First query below)
I'm looking for products whitch are type: Beds and i would like to show all options assigned to them - group them and count how many of them are. (like in photo below).

Second part of query:  (second query below)
When user click checkbox i would like to show and count only products that have checked options and count how many of this products are. (and here is problem )

First query:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT id_product) as productMatched, COUNT(id_product) as haveProducts, product_to_features.id_feature_value, product_to_features.id_feature, feature_value_langs.name,feature_value_langs.id_feature_value, products.active 
FROM product_to_features 
LEFT JOIN feature_value_langs 
   ON product_to_features.id_feature_value = feature_value_langs.id_feature_value 
LEFT JOIN products 
   ON product_to_features.id_product = products.id 
WHERE price_retail >= 655.00 
   AND price_retail <= 6455.00 
   AND height >= 0.0 AND height <= 120.0 
   AND width >= 0.0 AND width <= 262.0 
   AND depth >= 0.0 AND depth <= 276.0 
   AND product_to_features.id_feature_value IN (15981,15982,15983,16011,16012,16013,16019)  //its shows ids of bed sizes
   AND products.active = 1 
GROUP BY product_to_features.id_feature_value
```

And this shows:
[image: And this shows:]

Second query - not working as it should be:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT product_to_features.id_feature_value) as productMatched, COUNT(product_to_features.id_product) as haveProducts, product_to_features.id_feature_value, product_to_features.id_feature, id_product as ProductId, feature_value_langs.name, products.active 
FROM product_to_features 
LEFT JOIN feature_value_langs 
   ON product_to_features.id_feature_value = feature_value_langs.id_feature_value 
LEFT JOIN products 
   ON product_to_features.id_product = products.id 
WHERE price_retail >= 655 AND price_retail <= 6455 
   AND height >= 0 AND height <= 120 
   AND width >= 0 AND width <= 262 
   AND depth >= 0 AND depth <= 276 
   AND (product_to_features.id_feature_value IN (15981,15982,15983,16011,16012,16013,16019)  // (its first checkbox group where non is checked - so i send all values )
   OR product_to_features.id_feature_value IN ( 1096)  // 1096 - its checked option from second checkbox group)
   OR product_to_features.id_feature_value = 1483 )   // 1483 - is BED TYPE (must be)
  AND products.active = 1 
GROUP BY product_to_features.id_product having productMatched>2 
ORDER BY product_to_features.id_feature
```

For example if i check 80x200 it must refresh  all other checkboxes and show how many match current options (checked) and count matching products.

And here is my db structure:

```
DESCRIBE product_to_features

id  int(11) NO  PRI     auto_increment  
id_feature  int(10) unsigned    NO  MUL         
id_product  int(10) unsigned    NO  MUL         
id_feature_value    int(10) unsigned    NO  MUL     


desc `feature_value_langs`

id  int(11) NO  PRI     auto_increment  
id_feature_value    int(10) unsigned    NO  MUL         
id_lang int(10) unsigned    NO  MUL         
name    varchar(255)    YES MUL
```

Comment: See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: Are you using MySQL or MS SQL Server? Don't tag products not involved.

Comment: Sorry i clicked wrong suggestion - MySQL of course.

Comment: Also now would be a great time to learn about aliases and the importance of qualifying your column names - e.g. `FROM my_table x WHERE x.price_retail >= 655 AND x.price_retail <= 6455 AND x.height >= 0 AND x.height <= 120` etc.